# If im making dua in English while in sujood should i verbalise it or say it in my heart only( because its in English)?

Tags: salat, dua, muslim-practices, sajda

Assalamu Alaikum. I am a non arabic speaker. I want to make dua for certain things during sujood but i don’t know how to say them in arabic. Ive seen plenty of contrasting opinions on whether I can say my English duas out loud in sujood or not. Some say it is permissible to verbalise, but other say it is to only be said in my heart as saying duas in English/ other languages is equivalent to talking in Salah. Please advise as there’s something I really want to ask to Allah SWT. Jazakallah Khayran